# How to tell a function its specific source timeframe in code? Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The story is, for example, that I want get to the 200-hours EMA for using it in math, for obvious basic reasons. That's practically the 50-pip/4h or 800-pip/15min EMA.

In the built-in EMA Indicator, we can select the source timeframe but the question is: **how to simply tell the** `ta.ema(source,length)` **function *in code* to get the data from a specific timeframe?**

*Only this function, not any other in the code. (All the other expressions, functions in the indicator must work with the current timeframe.)* The source code of the built-in EMA indicator doesn't give a clue or it sticks out my eyes.

[image: Specific source timeframe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `request.security()` function for that.

See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) for more information.

Comment: As a final solution for others: we can leave the Security parameter alone with this form: request.security("", "15", close) 
In this case: ta.ema(request.security("", "15", close), 800)

You help me so lot, so fast, I'm in a constant progress thanks to you. :)